# AutoCAD-Plugin : C# : (System.Data.SQlite + SpatialiteSharp) ERROR in AutoCAD 2016/2017

Tags: system.data.sqlite, autocad-plugin

## **1) My Environment:**

. Windows 10 Pro (**licensed**) - 64 bits - 8GB Ram;

. AutoCAD (**licensed**) 2014/2015/2016/2017 64 bits (all HOTFIX and SERVICEPACK installed);

. Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition (for AutoCAD 2014);

. Visual Studio 2013 (for AutoCAD 2015/2016/2017);

. Antivirus : only Windows Defender.

---

## 2) Visual Studio 2013 Solution

- nuGet packages:

  - **System.Data.SQLite**
  - **SpatialiteSharp**
- Target: **.NET 4.5**

## 3) Database used for this test

. Database name : '**dbtest.sqlite**', [download here](https://www.autotopo.net/img/stackoverflow/Question_CSharpSpatialite/dbtest.sqlite) and save to **c:\temp**

. Database table : '**tb_test**'

. Database table **tb_test** fields:

- featureName : **TEXT**
- geometry    : **POLYGON**

---

## 4) Code Running on AutoCAD 2015 : OK

In Visual Lisp, I call **dbQuery** .NET method (file **MyCommands.cs**):

```
(setq result_query (dbQuery))
```

and will return a list:

```
[0] "FeatureName=first test area , MinX=101.23 , MinY=101.5 , MaxX=215.7 , MaxY=201.953 , Area=5532.771185"
[1] "FeatureName=second test area , MinX=100 , MinY=50 , MaxX=200 , MaxY=100 , Area=5000"
```

---

## **5) P R O B L E M :: Code running on Autocad 2016/2017 ::**

### Error : "Autodesk application has stopped working"

My plugin run ok on AutoCAD 2014 (.NET 4.0) and AutoCAD 2015 (.NET 4.5), but don't running on AutoCAD 2016/2017.

The code is the same, but changed only *AcMgd/AcCoreMgd/AcDbMgd* and Target DotNet Framework.

When debug my plugin, crash occurs on

```
connection.LoadExtension("mod_spatialite");
```

Then I receive a AutoCAD crash message window, saying:

#### Autodesk applicaton has stopped working

---

## 6) My AutoCAD 2017 plugin code

[clique here to download VisualStudio 2013 "**AutoCAD2017SpatialiteTest**" Solution](https://www.autotopo.net/img/stackoverflow/Question_CSharpSpatialite/AutoCAD2017SpatialiteTest.rar)

#### MyCommands.cs code

```
// Test (System.Data.SQLite + SpatialiteSharp) in AutoCAD 2017 plugin
// Date: March, 7, 2017.
//
//==============================================================
using System;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

using System.Data.SQLite;
using SpatialiteSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;


// This line is not mandatory, but improves loading performances
[assembly: CommandClass ( typeof ( AutoCAD2017SpatialiteTest.MyCommands ) )]

namespace AutoCAD2017SpatialiteTest
{

// This class is instantiated by AutoCAD for each document when
// a command is called by the user the first time in the context
// of a given document. In other words, non static data in this class
// is implicitly per-document!
public class MyCommands
    {

    private static readonly object Lock = new object ();

    private static bool _haveSetPath;


    //*******************************************************************
    // LispFunction is similar to CommandMethod but it creates a lisp 
    // callable function. Many return types are supported not just string
    // or integer.
    //
    //
    //
    [LispFunction ( "dbQuery", "dbQuery" )]
    public ResultBuffer dbQuery ( ResultBuffer args ) // This method can have any name
        {


        try
            {
            // Create Spatialite SQL Connection
            //
            string databaseName = @"c:\temp\dbtest.sqlite";
            string connectString = @"Data Source=" + databaseName + ";Version=3;";
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection ( connectString );

            /// Open the database and load in the Spatialite extension
            connection.Open ();

            /// Loads mod_spatialite.dll on the given connection
            ///
            lock ( Lock )
                {
                //Need to work out where the file is and add it to the path so it can load all the other dlls too
                if ( !_haveSetPath )
                    {
                    var spatialitePath = Path.Combine ( Path.GetDirectoryName ( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location ), (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86"), "spatialite" );

                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ( "PATH", spatialitePath + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ( "PATH" ) );

                    _haveSetPath = true;
                    }
                }
            connection.EnableExtensions ( true );
            connection.LoadExtension ( "mod_spatialite" );

            // Make some Spatialite function calls
            string sql = "SELECT featureName, ST_MINX(geometry), ST_MINY(geometry), ST_MAXX(geometry), ST_MAXY(geometry), ST_AREA(geometry) FROM tb_test ";

            double minX = 0.0, minY = 0.0, maxX = 0.0, maxY = 0.0, area = 0.0;
            string featureName = "";
            string result_query = "";
            // initialize resBuf list
            //
            ResultBuffer resBufCatch = new ResultBuffer ();
            resBufCatch.Add ( new TypedValue ( (int)LispDataType.ListBegin ) );

            // execute sql query 
            //
            using ( SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand ( sql, connection ) )
                {
                using ( SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader () )
                    {
                    while ( reader.Read () )
                        {
                        featureName = reader.GetString ( 0 );
                        minX = reader.GetDouble ( 1 );
                        minY = reader.GetDouble ( 2 );
                        maxX = reader.GetDouble ( 3 );
                        maxY = reader.GetDouble ( 4 );
                        area = reader.GetDouble ( 5 );

                        // define string with fields values from 'tb_test'
                        //
                        result_query = String.Format ( "FeatureName={0} , MinX={1} , MinY={2} , MaxX={3} , MaxY={4} , Area={5}", featureName, minX.ToString (), minY.ToString (), maxX.ToString (), maxY.ToString (), area );

                        // add result_query to buffer
                        //
                        resBufCatch.Add ( new TypedValue ( (int)LispDataType.Text, result_query ) );

                        }
                    }
                }
            // finalize resBuf list
            //
            resBufCatch.Add ( new TypedValue ( (int)LispDataType.ListEnd ) );

            // Close and clean up the database connection
            //
            connection.Close ();
            connection.Dispose ();

            // return result_query value to lisp function...
            //
            return resBufCatch;
            }
        catch ( System.Exception ex )
            {

            string exception_message = String.Format ( "Error : {0}", ex.Message );
            ResultBuffer resBufCatch = new ResultBuffer ();
            resBufCatch.Add ( new TypedValue ( (int)LispDataType.Text, exception_message ) );
            return resBufCatch;

            }


        }
    }
}
```

---

## 7) Question

Anybody help me run this AutoCAD2017 plugin?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an error report dialog like this one after the crash?

If yes, don't close the dialog and go to the folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp (%temp%). There must be a file named dumpdata.zip. In the archive, there is an xml file which can give you more details on the error and [a .dmp file you can open in Visual Studio.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx)

[image: AutoCAD Error Report dialog]

Comment: Yes, this **dumpdata.zip** file actually exists. Clique here to download [link](https://www.autotopo.net/img/stackoverflow/Question_CSharpSpatialite/dumpdata.zip).

Since it's my first POST here in StackOverFlow, it was not possible to illustrate my question with the images. It would be much clearer.

Thanks in advance, if you can analyze the file dumpdata.zip and draw some conclusion from it.

Comment: I see nothing useful in the .xml. For the .dmp, you need to open it in your Visual Studio and launch a debug session. Setup [the Autodesk symbol server first](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2011/06/public-symbols-for-autocad-2012.html). I can not do this for you, you need to do that on your computer.

Comment: I will check. Thank you.